# C++: How does boost intrusive pointer get destroyed?

Tags: c++, boost

I am learning boost in order to get comfortable with a code base.

I read the intrusive pointers documentation in boost and have some understanding about how it works. I have a question on how it gets destroyed.

Lets say I have an intrusive pointer to an object Foo A (which is allocated using new). Now if I create another object Foo B (using new) and make the same intrusive pointer to point to the newly created Foo object B.

Does memory created for object Foo A get destroyed in this process?

Comment: A `boost::intrusive_ptr` is the same as a `std::shared_ptr`. The only time it will deallocate any memory is when the reference count reaches 0. So making it point to another pointer won't do anything unless the ref count is 0. Since they are basically the same, I'd say that this would help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does as long as it is the last reference.  It differs from shared_ptr by utilizing an externally provided reference counting functions.